# How to check a certain CSS capability in a browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to check a certain CSS capability in a browser using JavaScript without detecting its vendor, userAgent, or appName?

Comment: Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: @Tomgrohl, Thanks in advance, no particular browser.  I wanted to test a CSS capability instead of asking for the browsers name, just like the proper way in testing a JavaScript capability.

Comment: Gotcha, added an answer that may be of some use.

Answer (score 3):

I've used something like this when creating a cssHook in jQuery:

**Testing for a CSS Property:**

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    divStyle = div.style;

    $.support.boxSizing =
    divStyle.MozBoxSizing === ''? 'MozBoxSizing' : 
    (divStyle.WebkitBoxSizing === ''? 'WebkitBoxSizing' : 
    (divStyle.MsBoxSizing === ''? 'MsBoxSizing' :
    (divStyle.boxSizing === ''? 'boxSizing' : false)));

    div = divStyle = null; //release memory
```

**Testing for a CSS Property Value:**

```
var div = document.createElement( "div" ),
    css = "background-image:gradient(linear,left top,right bottom, from(#9f9), to(white));background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-moz-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-o-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-ms-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:-khtml-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));background-image:linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);background-image:-khtml-linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);";    

    div.style.cssText = css;

$.support.linearGradient =
    div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "-moz-linear-gradient" )  > -1 ? '-moz-linear-gradient' :
    (div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "-webkit-gradient" )  > -1 ? '-webkit-gradient' :
    (div.style.backgroundImage.indexOf( "gradient" )  > -1 ? 'gradient' : false));

    div= null; //release memory
```

Comment: Fantastic example and you don't even need jQuery to use this.

Answer (score 2):

See [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this question is that the technique is different for each property.

The general idea is to use JavaScript to attempt to use the property, and then to test for some defined behaviour of the property.

See the source code to Modernizr, a feature detection library:

http://www.modernizr.com/ - http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-2.0.3.js

For instance:

```
// http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/
tests['rgba'] = function() {
    // Set an rgba() color and check the returned value

    setCss('background-color:rgba(150,255,150,.5)');

    return contains(mStyle.backgroundColor, 'rgba');
};
```

In a browser that does not support `rgba`, the returned value would not contain `rgba`.

Also, as suggested by @DanielB, look at `jQuery.support` for more inspiration. Here's the source:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/support.js

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) which can tell you which features are available for the current visitor.

Comment: Took a bit of crack at this here: http://www.fractured-state.com/2011/07/browser-color-override-test-for-modernizr/