# if browser CSS3

Tags: php, css, cross-browser

How do we check to see if the browser browsing a webpage is CSS3 capable. I know how to check for which browser is coming in using PHP but how do we check specifically that the browser supports CSS3.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: As a side note to the answers that have been posted, CSS is designed in such a way that browsers ignore CSS that they don't recognize. So, for example, IE7 will ignore `border-radius:5px`. This means that for solely implementing CSS3 stuff, you don't necessarily have to detect what's available. This, of course, depends on what you're doing and how you're handling fallbacks.

Comment: It is for the purpose of building a fallback to JQuery if transitions are not possible

Answer (score 3):

PHP (and I imagine any other server-side technology) has no idea about a browser's CSS capabilities. However on the client side, you can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) and handle rendering of your page based on the guides it gives you about what CSS3 properties a browser supports.

Answer (score 1):

No browser supports all of CSS 3. Many browsers support bits of CSS 3.

You can detect some CSS 3 features with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-css), but that uses client side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 is not 'one' feature that you can detect. Browsers implement parts of it one after another. So, for example, IE 9 implements parts of CSS3 like box-shadow, but does not support some other things.

What you could do is make a list of browsers that support a given CSS3 feature and test the user agent. If you do this, http://caniuse.com/ may be a good help.

But I dont recommend this. The best way to check certain features will be client-side, for example with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

**Edit**: If you need to provide a fallback, do it client-side too. Modernizr optionally includes a library named [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), with which you can easily load files if the browser doesnt support something. This could look like this:

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.csstransitions,
   nope : ['jquery.js', 'transitions-fallback.js']
});
```

This code snippet would test for csstransitions and if they are not available, it would load jQuery and the transitions fallback js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a blanket check because of the patchy support of CSS3 and the variances between browsers.  See here: [How to check a certain CSS capability in a browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276345/how-to-check-a-certain-css-capability-in-a-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use Modernzir - http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is some web tools that can check how your browser is css3 compatible:

[Selector test](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/)

[Acid3](http://acid3.acidtests.org/)

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-css)

And there is a lot more...

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's get_browser function you can do

```
$cssversion = get_browser(null, true)['cssversion'];
```

This will tell you the highest version the browser supports but as others have stated browser do not support every attribute within a version.