# If/Else Javascript statement to disable transition animation if failed

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, animation, transition

I have a navigation bar that has a hamburger menu button.  The navigation menu worked on all browsers before I added an open/close javascript animation.  On a few older browsers, the script will unfortunately prevent the menu from opening at all if clicked.  But it works on most newer browsers.  I need to make the script stop if it doesn't execute properly to let the older browsers be able to open the navigation bar.

I have written an easy fix to stop the script from executing if "something" is false.

```
if (something == false) {
  <!--animation script goes here -->
stop
}
```

Changing "something" to different things has given me interesting results.  If I change it to

```
if (data == false) {
  <!--animation script goes here -->
stop
}
```

Then it will completely stop the script even in the browsers that ran the animation perfectly before.

My question is, what can I replace "something" with to make the script stop if it didn't run successfully?

Here is the animation script, if you need it. (Don't let it scare you.  All I need is to stop this script if the animation fails.)

```
! function() {
"use strict";

function e() {
    var e, t = document.createElement("div"),
        n = {
            transition: "transitionend",
            OTransition: "otransitionend",
            MozTransition: "transitionend",
            WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd"
        };
    for (e in n)
        if (n.hasOwnProperty(e) && void 0 !== t.style[e]) return n[e];
    return !1
}

function t(e) {
    var t = {};
    e = e || window.event, t.evTarget = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
    var n = t.evTarget.getAttribute("data-target");
    return t.dataTarget = n ? document.querySelector(n) : !1, t
}

function n(e) {
    var t = e.style.height;
    e.style.height = "auto";
    var n = getComputedStyle(e).height;
    return e.style.height = t, e.offsetHeight, n
}

function a(e, t) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var n = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        n.initEvent(t, !0, !1), e.dispatchEvent(n)
    } else e.fireEvent("on" + t)
}

function r(e, t) {
    e.classList.remove("collapse"), e.classList.add("collapsing"), t.classList.remove("collapsed"), t.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !0), e.style.height = n(e), u ? e.addEventListener(u, function() {
        s(e)
    }, !1) : s(e)
}

function i(e, t) {
    e.classList.remove("collapse"), e.classList.remove("in"), e.classList.add("collapsing"), t.classList.add("collapsed"), t.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !1), e.style.height = getComputedStyle(e).height, e.offsetHeight, e.style.height = "0px"
}

function s(e) {
    e.classList.remove("collapsing"), e.classList.add("collapse"), e.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !1), "0px" !== e.style.height && (e.classList.add("in"), e.style.height = "auto")
}

function o(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var n = t(e),
        a = n.dataTarget;
    return a.classList.contains("in") ? i(a, n.evTarget) : r(a, n.evTarget), !1
}

function l(e) {
    function n() {
        try {
            i.parentNode.removeChild(i), a(i, "closed.bs.alert")
        } catch (e) {
            window.console.error("Unable to remove alert")
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = t(e),
        i = r.dataTarget;
    if (!i) {
        var s = r.evTarget.parentNode;
        s.classList.contains("alert") ? i = s : s.parentNode.classList.contains("alert") && (i = s.parentNode)
    }
    return a(i, "close.bs.alert"), i.classList.remove("in"), u && i.classList.contains("fade") ? i.addEventListener(u, function() {
        n()
    }, !1) : n(), !1
}

function c(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
    return t.parentElement.classList.toggle("open"), !1
}

function d(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
    return t.parentElement.classList.remove("open"), e.relatedTarget && "dropdown" !== e.relatedTarget.getAttribute("data-toggle") && e.relatedTarget.click(), !1
}
for (var u = e(), g = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=collapse]"), v = 0, f = g.length; f > v; v++) g[v].onclick = o;
for (var p = document.querySelectorAll("[data-dismiss=alert]"), h = 0, m = p.length; m > h; h++) p[h].onclick = l;
for (var L, T = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=dropdown]"), y = 0, E = T.length; E > y; y++) L = T[y], L.setAttribute("tabindex", "0"), L.onclick = c, L.onblur = d}();
```

I was thinking someone may be able to just say something like "if (transition == false) { stop }" or something that does that, that would be perfect.

Comment: just a little tip: `transition == false` is the same as `!transition` and `transition` for true. has nothing to do with the question though.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506349/if-browser-css3) is something that might help you.

Comment: @KevinKloet Thank you for sharing that.  I wasn't aware that this javascript animation had anything to do with ccs3!  So, with that information, what should I add before and after the animation script to make it not execute for incompatible browsers?

Comment: follow [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-detect-css3-support-in-browsers-with-javascript--net-16444) step by step tutorial. alternatively you could use the [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) library.

Comment: Thank you @KevinKloet!  You are amaizng!  Feel free to answer this question with copy/paste and cite your source, I will choose you as best answer if you do.  Thank you again, I appreciate your time so much.  You are amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

Let's begin by determining how we want to call our function. We'll keep things simple here; something like the following should do the trick:

```
if ( supports('textShadow') ) {
   document.documentElement.className += ' textShadow';
}
```

That should be the final function call. When we pass a CSS property name to the `supports()` function, it'll return a boolean. If true, we'll attach a className to the `documentElement`, or `<html>`. This will then provide us with a new 'class' name to hook onto, from our stylesheet.

**Step 2**

Next, we'll construct the `supports()` function.

```
var supports = (function() {

})();
```

Why aren't we making supports equal to a standard function? The answer is because we have a bit of prep work to do first, and there's absolutely no reason to repeat those tasks over and over every single time the function is called. In cases like this, it's best to make supports equal to whatever is returned from the self-executing function.

**Step 3**

To test whether or not the browser supports specific properties, we need to create a *dummy* element, for testing. This generated element will never actually be inserted into the DOM; think of it as a test dummy!

`var div = document.createElement('div');`

As you're probably aware of, there are a handful of vendor-prefixes that we can use, when working with CSS3 properties:

```
-moz
-webkit
-o
-ms
-khtml
```

Our JavaScript will need to filter through those prefixes, and test them. So, let's place them in an array; we'll call it, vendors.

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' ');
```

Using the `split()` function to create an array from a string is admittedly lazy, but it saves a handful of seconds!

As we'll be filtering through this array, let's be good boys and girls, and cache the length of the array as well.

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
len = vendors.length;
```

The prep work, above, is static, in nature, and doesn't need to be repeated every time we call `supports()`. This is why we only run it once, when the page loads. Now, let's return the function that will actually be assigned to the supports variable.

```
return function(prop) {

};
```

The beauty of closures is that, even though `supports()` is equal to that returned function, it still has access to the `div`, `vendors`, and `len` variables.

**Step 4**

The immediate test: if the passed property is available to the div's style attribute, we know the browser supports the property; so `return true`.

```
return function(prop) {
   if ( prop in div.style ) return true;
};
```

Think of, say, the `text-shadow` CSS3 property. Most modern browsers support it, without the need for a vendor prefix. With that in mind, why filter through all of the prefixes if we don't need to? That's why we place this check at the top.

**Step 5**

You're likely used to typing CSS3 property names, like so: `-moz-box-shadow`. However, if, in Firebug, you review the style object, you'll find that it's spelled, `MozBoxShadow`. As such, if we test:

```
'mozboxShadow' in div.style // false
```

False will be returned. This value is case-sensitive.

Case Sensitive
This means that, if the user passes boxShadow to the `supports()` function, it'll fail. Let's think ahead, and check if the first letter of the argument is lowercase. If it is, we'll fix the error for them.

```
return function(prop) {
   if ( prop in div.style ) return true;

   prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
      return val.toUpperCase();
   });

};
```

Regular expressions to the rescue! Above, we're checking if there is a single lowercase letter at the beginning of the string (^). Only on the condition that one is found, we use the `toUpperCase()` function to capitalize the letter.

**Step 6**

We next need to filter through the vendors array, and test if there's a match. For instance, if box-shadow is passed, we should test if the style attribute of the div contains any of the following:

```
MozBoxShadow
WebkitBoxShadow
MsBoxShadow
OBoxShadow
KhtmlBoxShadow
```

If a match is found, we can `return true`, because the browser does, indeed, provide support for box shadows!

```
return function(prop) {
   if ( prop in div.style ) return true;

   prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
      return val.toUpperCase();
   });

   while(len--) {
      if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
            return true;       
      } 
   }  
};
```

Though we could use a for statement to filter through the array, there's no real need to in this case.

The order isn't important
while statements are quicker to type, and require fewer characters
There's a tiny performance improvement
Don't be confused by `vendors[len] + prop;` simply replace those names with their real-life values: `MozBoxShadow`.

**Step 7**

But, what if none of those values match? In that case, the browser doesn't seem to support the property, in which case we should return false.

```
while(len--) {
   if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
         return true;       
   } 
} 
return false;
```

That should do it for our function! Let's test it out, by applying a className to the html element, if the browser supports, say, the `text-stroke` property (which only webkit does).

```
if ( supports('textStroke') ) {
   document.documentElement.className += ' textStroke';
}
```

**Step 8:**

Usage
With a class name that we can now hook onto, let's try it out in our stylesheet.

```
/* fallback */
h1 {
   color: black;
}   

/* text-stroke support */
.textStroke h1 {
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
}
```

**Final Source Code**

```
var supports = (function() {
   var div = document.createElement('div'),
      vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
      len = vendors.length;

   return function(prop) {
      if ( prop in div.style ) return true;

      prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
         return val.toUpperCase();
      });

      while(len--) {
         if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
            // browser supports box-shadow. Do what you need.
            // Or use a bang (!) to test if the browser doesn't.
            return true;
         } 
      }
      return false;
   };
})();

if ( supports('textShadow') ) {
   document.documentElement.className += ' textShadow';
}
```

source: [copy pasted from here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-detect-css3-support-in-browsers-with-javascript--net-16444)

For a more comprehensive solution, refer to the [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) library.